My vivitar v3800n film advance lever is stuck and the frame count says s
So i have a vivitar v3800n and i want to take photos but i can't because the lever is stuck and the frame counter says S instead of 1 for some reason it was working ladt year but we moved and I put it in a chest drawer and since then if has had this issue I don't know what to do
